# How to Hide and Show Header and Footer Toolbar on Pageshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im working with jquery mobile in my project and i implement a header and footer toolbar.

what i try to do is:

always when i open a page, i want that the toolbars are hidden, and only when i click 1 time on the touchscreen i want to open them.

I have a script from a friend of mine and it works,

but i have to do a double click on the touchscreen to open them...

exists anyway to do this only with 1 click?

Note: i have in my project several `data-role="pages"`

my code:

**HTML5:**

```
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer" data-fullscreen="true" class="hidden">TESTE</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer2" data-fullscreen="true" class="hidden">TESTE</div>
```

**Script:**

```
  function enableHeaderFooter() {
    $(document).off("touchend", enableHeaderFooter);
    $("header, footer").removeClass("hidden");
  }
  $(document).on("touchend", enableHeaderFooter);
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden{display:none}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the header and footer CSS classes that contain the declaration "display: none", and use an javascript touch event handler bound to `window` to show them by removing that class.
Also note that data-role="header" is a bit silly, since html has a  element for this. Secondarily, note that you've given both `id=footer` which is *guaranteed* to cause problems.

```
<header class="hidden" ...>...</header>
...
<footer class="hidden" ...>...</footer>
```

+

```
<script>
  function enableHeaderFooter() {
    $(document).off("touchend", enableHeaderFooter);
    $("header, footer").removeClass("hidden");
  }
  $(document).on("touchend", enableHeaderFooter);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip... i have done what you say.. but the toolbars doesn´t open anymore....

Comment: have add the class hidden, and in my css file i wrote:  .hidden{display:none}

Comment: Look at my code pls... Have done an update with your solution#

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YWBQX/ uses this code, with "click" instead of "touchend" to show it working in a normal browser - click the lower right panel and presto, header and footer show up. You can try "touchstart" just in case the browser you're testing with is a little broken on touch events.